# Can you modify the UIImagePickerController from its default layout

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, customizing

I am deciding on wether to use UIImagePickerController or to build a custom subview for the camera (like Instagram) to capture images or too use UIImagePickerController.

Is it possible to modify the text, images or layout of UIImagePickerController?

(I see some duplicate stack overflow questions saying no, but they all all over 3 years old and not using ios 7, so sorry for posting again.)

Comment: Same issue, I need to make changes in default imagepickercontroller....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Yet, but yes you can add an `overlay` to add more features, Yes you can use [AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5) to create fully `customized camera app`.